# Fast find for indices by ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, performance

I have million of objects each have an unique ID - number.
Each object for making it simple contains name

They objects are being added into array.

Into this array i'm adding and removing objects.

In order to remove object I have the id, and then need to find the index in the array and splice it out.

In my case i have allot of objects and can have allot of removes operations. so in case i have 1000 removes. and all of this objects ids are stored in the end of the array, than i will run over the all 1 million objects till i find them.

Storing the index in the object after adding is not good, because every each remove i need to update the indices of all objects stored after the removed one.
For example removing the first 1000 will cause updating the rest of the 1M-1000 items indices.

My question is, what is the best solution for my problem?

**-- UPDATE --**

for example: My flat array look like this after adding 1M objects

[ obj1, obj2, obj3, .... obj1000000 ]

I want to remove now the object obj1000000. For finding which index this object
was inserted to i need to run over all the array (or till i found the item) and compare the current item id with my obj1000000 id, and break out from the loop when found. Then remove the item by it's index.

If i would store the index of each object in the object itself after it being added to the array, i would have to update the rest of the objects indices after removing one.

For example: `obj1` will contains property `index=0`, `obj2` will have `index=1` and so on. To remove `obj5` i just get its property `index` which is `4` and remove it. but now `obj6` which has `index=5` is incorrect. and should be `4`. and obj7 should be `5` and so on. so update must be done.

My `SmartArray` holds an TypedArray created in some size. And i'm expending it if needed. When push is called. I'm simply set the value in the last item `this._array[this.length++] = value;` (Checking of course if to expand the array)

```
SmartArray.prototype.getArray = function () {
    return this._array.subarray(0, this.length);
}

SmartArray.prototype.splice = function (index, removeCount) {

    if (index + removeCount < this.length) {
       var sub = this._array.subarray(index + removeCount, this.length);
       this._array.set(sub, index);
    } else {
        removeCount = this.length - index;
    }

    this.length -= removeCount;
}
```

It is working very fast, `subarray` doesn't create a new array. And `set` is working very fast as well.

Comment: Why are you using an array at all? Splicing an array is as costly as linearly searching it.

Comment: I'm using web gl for drawing and this required flat arrays. I've developed a smart typed array that not actually creating new array every splice.. and it is working fine. The bottleneck is the search for the indices to remove

Comment: `splice` isn't creating new arrays indeed, but it does need to reorder all indices after the removed item… Or do you use sparse arrays? Please show us your smart typed array implementation.

Comment: Make a map of id to index?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the ids are stored in the end of the array or what you mean by storing the index in the object is not good.

Comment: I will update my post with more explanation

Comment: I cannot map Id to index because then i will have the same problem of updating all the items (after removing one) instead of searching for the item. I don't know if it is more or less expensive from performances point of view

Comment: Well there's the ES2015 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) type supported in Chrome and Firefox and Node.  A Map instance is iterable (in insertion order), and it allows fast lookup by key.

Comment: can you sort your array and do a binary search to find the correct object?

Comment: I can't sort the array because the insert order is the drawing order.. Z order. first insert first drawn. I know that i can use depth buffer in web-gl. but for better performances i prefer to disable this function.

Comment: @Pointy I don't understand how `Map` will help me here. If i want fast lookup i would still have run over and update the values after remove, or i got it totally wrong?

Comment: If you remove something from a map, it's removed. The lookups on other ID values still work.

Comment: Yes i know that. But lets say that my item key is the ID of the object. and the value will be the index (i guess this is how you planned it).. so when i remove an item from the map that others item value (index) are now wrong and need to be set again, and this is what i tried to avoid

Answer (score 0):

The standard solutions for this problem are

- balanced (binary) trees,
- hash tables.

They take respectively O(Log(N)) and O(1) operations per search/insertion/deletion on average.

Both can be implemented in an array. You will find numerous versions of them by web search.

Comment: You mean that every remove i will index all the tree again ? because when remove is being done i need to update the values of the leafs which change the tree

Comment: There's no reason not to use the built-in data structures available in JavaScript.

Comment: @RazizaO: you should read about binary trees and hash table to see how they work.

Comment: ... and then take time to consider that simple object property lookup and the ES2015 Map mechanism are already implemented using best-practice key-lookup data structures.

Comment: I think i really thinking wrong, or you guys didn't understand me correctly.. If i'm saving in hash table/binary tree/Map by the key, what should be the value ? If you mean to save the index, than removing the item from the hash table/binary tree/Map will than make all the items added after the removed one offset by 1. and so and on.. If i'm completely off, please direct me to your thoughts